# Is there a relay package which can be triggered by a numeric coded pulse?

Tags: relay, programmable-logic

I would like to design a simple relay which is triggered by a series of pulses rather than just a high signal.

e.g. the relay would have a serial data input. The relay would need to be "preset" with the code which will trigger it - e.g. 119. Then if you send it 01110111, the relay latches. Then sending a reset code (or the same code) could unlatch it.

I know this would be a fairly simple logic circuit to make, to drive a standard relay, but I'm wondering if such a product already exists, what it would be called so I can find it in component catalogues.

Update: the signal would be sent from an existing system which can be programmed to send pretty much any digital signal sequence (e.g. faking RS232 or other encodings) but only has one output line, and I can add line level conversion if needed.

Update 2: as I only have one driving line, I cannot provide a clock signal, so it must be asynchronous serial.

Comment: The gadget you are looking for is called a "microcontroller". You just need to write the code for your desired function. Any more specific information would be a shopping question, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson As I mentioned I could build this in logic, so I don't need an MCU.

Comment: How will the user send the value 01110111?  Keypad, switches, ...?

Comment: What are the two codes you've settled on. Or are you flexible on that?

Comment: @Yoshimitsu Hey! Of course the OP is using a toggle switch and a momentary to clock those bits in like we used to do back in the day. ;)

Comment: @Yoshimitsu I have updated the answer - it's driven by another existing circuit.

Comment: @jonk I'd want to "program" it, i.e. set the code(s) but this could be one-off or dip switches.

Comment: @scipilot So. You could use four groups of DIP switches. Two of them set the two codes (on and off), internally. Two of them are externally available and can be set and then "tried" by pushing a momentary? Would that be about it?

Comment: consider using a standard remote control decoder chip, eg [HT12D](https://www.holtek.com/productdetail/-/vg/2_12d)

Comment: Using the same code for on and off is dodgy. If it ever got out of step you wouldn't know. Better to use a 7-bit code and bit 8 to set or reset.

Comment: Thanks @BruceAbbott.

Comment: Agreed @Transitor it would be bound to go wrong.

Comment: "asynchronous serial" and "simple logic circuit" do not come well together, because the need for a clock and clock synchronization logic on receiver side quickly moves it out of "simple" category. I cannot imagine someone choosing 10-20 ICs over one 8-pin MCU chip. Also, RS232 does not have encoding, it is electrical interface.

Comment: @Maple yes I agree it's cannot be as simple I first hoped. I'm happy with the "No" answer. By encoding I meant start/stop bit length, 7/8bit, parity etc. probably used the wrong word - the signal structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this would be a fairly simple logic circuit to make, ... but I'm wondering if such a product already exists, ...

It probably doesn't exist.
When you have the luxury of one or more wires you'd typically use a versatile or robust solution.
One which offers more than just unsolicited command shouting, such as I2C.
One that isn't as susceptible to noise as a single ended wire. Such as RS-485.
One which layer 2 protocol contains data integrity checks, such as CAN-bus or MODBUS-RTU.

Shouting 01110111 over a wire won't be a suitable solution in the industry for obvious reasons.
It is however widely used in cheap 433 MHz remote control sockets. A set of dip switches then configures the numbers it will listen to.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using RS424, 232 and other protocols in other areas but in this case I am limited. I guess this question should be re-posted as what is a reliable single-wire protocol now I know there's no such relay.